# Search field in Excel with delimited text

Tags: excel, text, vlookup, delimited

I am having a data in such format (DELIMITED TEXT)

[image: Delimited Text Data]

How do I `Vlookup` `"F88"` to get `1` dynamic value.

[image: Vlookup particular data from the text]

Thanks a ton

Comment: You have "DELIMITED TEXT" in a single cell. Like literally you have `'F88','66','149','','','53','13','45','11','92','43','','',''   ` in one cell? And you want to look something up in that delimited text? This is entirely unclear what your SPREADSHEET looks like and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JNevill Yes Sir,

Comment: Why value `66` is returned when you input `F86`? Why not `149`? What is the logic here. What if I input `45`, would I get `11` back?

Comment: @JNevill I did Update my question with images if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With your posted data in **A1**, give this a try:

```
Sub DataGrsbber()
    Dim s As String
    s = Replace([A1], "'", "")
    ary = Split(s, ",")
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary) - 1
        If ary(i) = "F88" Then
            MsgBox ary(i + 1)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To retrieve the value into a cell, try this User Defined Function:

```
Public Function Retriever(BigString As String, LittleString As String) As String
    Dim s As String
    s = Replace(BigString, "'", "")
    ary = Split(s, ",")
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary) - 1
        If ary(i) = LittleString Then
            Retriever = ary(i + 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    Retriever = ""
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful, but @Gary how do I take a dynamic value, and instead of msgbox paste it on a cell. I am a newbie on VBA   Thanks.

Comment: @Sadsamosa  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thanks, this is helped me a lot now

Comment: Hi, @Gary how do I take the whole column.for delimited text.